# bind key sequence to Escape, zsh

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, vi-mode

How would I map `jj` to `Esc` in zsh?

I'm trying to recreate a key-mapping that I have setup in vim, where I have `jj` mapped to `ESC` so that whenever I double-press `j`, it sends the an `<Esc>` to vim--allowing me to enter normal mode with greater convenience.

I've already tried `bindkey 'jj' ^[`, and I'm about to try `bindkey 'jj' ^[[`, but I doubt that it'll work.  I also checked the list of commands provided by zsh in normal mode, but I didn't see anything that contained `normal` or `escape`.

**NOTE**
The `^[` characters in my `~/.zshrc` file are actual hard coded escapes; not just the characters `^` and `[`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need `-s` to bind actual strings instead of widgets:

```
bindkey -s jj '\e'
```

Though you probably want to map `jj` to the `vi-cmd-mode` widget here:

```
bindkey jj vi-cmd-mode
```

(note that's for binding in insert mode, not normal/command mode)

Comment: the second one works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: **NOTE** setting `KEYTIMEOUT` seems to break the key-binding.

Comment: @AlexejMagura just adding: setting KEYTIMEOUT too low prohibits zle from recognizing double press.

Comment: @AlexejMagura , What should be the KEYTIMEOUT ?

Comment: @Jdeep, `export KEYTIMEOUT=10`